# C# Net.Mail e-mail marked as spam but only from dedicated server

Tags: c#, email, iis, spam-prevention, email-spam

some providers like "live.com", "virgilio.it" or "libero.it" marks all email sent from my website as SPAM. My website is hosted in my dedicated server on Aruba SPA.
I have already tryed with some settings, adding alternative view or manipulating Headers, but with no success!
The strange fact is that if I send the email using my local machine, the email are received without problem, there aren't marked as SPAM!!
For sending email, i use an external SMTP server (smtp.**mydomain**.it)

My dedicated server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5, my local machine Machine is running Windows 10 IIS 10.

Please help me!

here my code

```
Dim mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Dim invio As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
        invio.Host = serverSMTP
        invio.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        invio.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Dim Credentials As Net.NetworkCredential = New Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
        invio.Credentials = Credentials

        mail.Sender = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(mittente, displayname, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
        mail.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(mittente, displayname, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
        mail.ReplyToList.Add(New Net.Mail.MailAddress(mittente, displayname, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
        mail.To.Add(destinatario)
        mail.Subject = oggetto
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        'mail.Body = corpo
        mail.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        mail.Headers.Add("Message-Id", String.Concat("<", Now.ToString("yyMMdd"), ".", Now.ToString("HHmmss"), Mid(username, InStr(username, "@"), Len(username)), ">"))

        Dim plainView As System.Net.Mail.AlternateView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(corpo, "<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "text/plain")
        Dim htmlView As System.Net.Mail.AlternateView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(corpo, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "text/html")
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView)
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)

        invio.Send(mail)
```

Comment: Could you please post your code that you have written for sending email?

Comment: Email servers are difficult to manage, and if you are running them on a major hosting network then you are often blacklisted because of the activities of others on the same network.  Even the big guys occasionally get blacklisted.  I suggest you enter your email server on the blacklist checker sites like http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and figure out what to do after that.  There are many things that can help improve your score against spam filters, frankly, unless you're planning to run an email business, it's just not worth it.. pay for a service.

Comment: Ty all, i've posted my code.
@Erik i understand about activities on the same network, but i have a stati IP for my server and i don't understand why from local machine with dynamic IP working! I use same SMTP address as Dedicated Server.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have a static ip.  When a host is blacklisted, it typically blacklists the entire ip block for that hosting provider.

Comment: So...you mean that my IP is listed and emails marked as spam even I use an external SMTP server like Google on port 465....and there is not solution, right?

Comment: Try Erik for your support. The hosting is investigating about the problem and I have solved the problem using a Gmail SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that, your server IP have set rDNS/PTR record correctly. You can verify it from [here..](http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx) If it is not set then you can contact your hosting provider to set it for your server IP Address.

Check your server IP Address blacklisted or not from [here](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx). If it is blacklisted then you need to diagnose the root cause and take corrective actions for it. After that, submit your IP Address removal request to the blacklisted ISPs/RBLs.

Check your IP Address reputation. If it is poor then you have to check the root cause of it like email compromised or any other then wait for your IP address reputation update to general or good.

Add proper [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records to your domain from which you are sending emails. If these records are not set then you can either engage your web developer OR hosting provider to set these records for you.

Comment: Ty Herbal, you are right. I've contacted the hosting and they told me about rDns and Ptr. But I'm not sure that is the right way...I don't use any SMTP server on my machine, Mx records are managed by hosting...how I can set Ptr or nDns if I don't have SMTP server? I just opened a ticket for solve the problem and the technicians are investigating about the problem. Otherwise I solved the problem using Gmail SMTP!

Comment: You can not set rDNS/PTR record from your end as it is required to set on IP Address. Hence, your hosting provider should setup it for you. 

You can use third party SMTP service, but it will pass your server IP Address as sender IP Address. Hence, you may encounter such problem.

Hope, you should be able to send email from your dedicated server once rDNS/PTR, DKIM and SPF records are set.

Comment: The hosting has investigate about my problem and told me that the spam score of my IP was high. Now they reset the spam score and everything is working but for the future I asked for activate rDns, Skin and SPF